# I cannot install these packages in CentOS 5

Tags: linux, rpm, centos5, odoo-9

I am trying to install Odoo 9 in my Centos 5 machine. When I use the Odoo RPM, this error appears:

```
    babel is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    nodejs-clean-css is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    nodejs-less is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-decorator is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-feedparser is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-mock is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-passlib is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-psutil is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-requests is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-vobject is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
    python-werkzeug is needed by odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch
```

I spent a lot of hours installing all packages one by one using corresponding RPM files or using setup.py files, however, for some reason, that installations are not recognized when I try to install Odoo.

What else can I do?

Comment: Nothing installed via `setup.py` (unless it creates an rpm that you install) will *ever* be seen as providing something that an rpm package needs. Where did the `odoo` package come from? Have you tried just running `yum install odoo-9.0_20151112-1.noarch.rpm` (or whatever the rpm filename is)?

Comment: This seems like package for CentOS 6, because Centos have python 2.4. No way to install it on CentOS6.

Comment: @EtanReisner The errors I posted were produced when I ran the command you suggested.

Comment: CentOS 5 has python 2.4. CentOS 6 has python 2.6. CentOS 7 has python 2.7. That package is clearly expecting python 2.7+ and so cannot work, by default, on CentOS 5. Are you sure that package is supposed to work on CentOS 5? Where did you get that `odoo` RPM from?